# C# How to Handle Constant Stream of WebSocket Messages?

Tags: c#, websocket, traffic

I have a websocket client that is reciving a rate of messages from a stream api at around ~20 a second. I've been looking for a best practice on how to handle them, but I've not been able to find anything (or I'm missing some specific terms I need to serach for).

Currently as soon as an message is recived I store it in a list and after X timespan I copy the list into a new instance, clear the main list, and then process all the events in the instance, repeating on a timer. I can't process the messages in real time as there is extra processing that needs to be done per message.

This seemed to work fine at first but there is a ongoing race condition if a message arrives in the milliseconds it takes to instance the list it will throw an exception that the 'Destination array was not long enough'.

TL;DR Whats the best way to handle and process constant rate of messages like this?

Comment: Paste your code [mcve]

Comment: Put them into concurrent collection (like ConcurrentQueue), process with separate thread (s).

Comment: @TheGeneral So I did see your original comment and I don't really think there is much I can add to the OP. I also don't feel the current code will help...
Message arrives, I put it into a list, on a timer I instance the list into a new list, an error is thrown if a new message arrives in the time it takes to instance the list.

Comment: So if you are looking for a process buffer. Just use a concurrent collection, or an unbound channel (pull solution). However, a perpetual TPL Dataflow `ActionBlock` (or Rx) could give you some advantages (push solution), like being able to process things in parallel ect without having to worry about polling and cycling a collection.

Comment: You could look at putting a `lock` on your list while you're working on it - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: @Evk
I've not heard of a ConcurrentQueue so I'll look into it.

Comment: @Kayndarr What happens when adding into the list if a lock is active?

Comment: @cooltrain The code attempting to access the list is blocked until the lock is released - so you want to do as little as possible inside the lock so that the subscriber can get back to writing your messages into the new list. I've done something similar, reading from a message stream rather than web sockets - swap the list out with a blank list inside the lock and then release it, and let a different thread handle all the processing on the 'full' list. Your web socket implementation is probably different to what we did, but we were easily handling >1000 messages/sec and the lock worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comments about using `lock` to protect your lists while you make the switch, this is the general idea of how I did something similar - mostly from memory so apologies if anything is unclear - see [the Microsoft doco on locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) for more detail:

We had two classes - a 'reader', which subscribes to the messages, and a 'processor', which handles processing the data.

In the 'reader', we define a 'lock object' that we will 'lock' on, as well as a reusable List object to write to:

```
readonly object LockObj = new object();
List<string> _myReadingList = new List<string>();
```

The 'reader' is running a thread that, as messages are received, adds values to a list (in our case it was a dictionary, but same deal). While it's adding to the list, it locks on that lock object:

```
lock (LockObj)
{
    _myReadingList.Add("Data Goes Here");
}
```

At regular intervals, a thread in the 'processor' will make a call to swap the list out - we used `WaitOne` on this thread to block it between intervals. Our interval was 200ms at a minimum, growing up to 1000ms if no messages were coming through for any reason.

The swapping code, written in the 'reader' (with access to the same 'List' object that we write to, `_myReadingList`) looks like this:

```
internal void SwapLists(List<string> emptyList, out List<string> loadedList)
{
    lock(LockObj)
    {
        loadedList = _myReadingList;
        _myReadingList= emptyList;
    }
}
```

Note that since the same object is being locked in both cases, only one of these two pieces of code can be running at the same time (attempting to lock on an object that is already locked results in the thread having to wait for that object to be released). If the 'reader' thread is writing to the list, the 'processing' thread calling this method is blocked, and vice versa.

SwapLists is called from the 'processor', which has its own reusable List object:

`List<string> _myProcessingList = new List<string>()`

The call to the SwapLists method, from the `processing` class's thread then looks like this:

```
List<string> loadedList;
<readingClassReference>.SwapLists(_myProcessingList , out loadedList);
_myProcessingList = loadedList;
```

So, you've got two conflict conditions that can occur that are handled safely:

- If 'reader' is in the process of writing to the List, 'processor' is temporarily blocked from completing the 'SwapLists' call - for a tiny fraction of time.
- If 'processor' is in the process of swapping the lists, 'reader' is temporarily blocked from adding its current payload to the List.

At 20 messages per second, the time scales involved where the threads are blocked should be irrelevant - we were able to easily process several thousand messages per second in our case.